Romantic Indian drama about two sisters
It's an Indian movie. In the opening scene, two sisters (who aren't twins) are competing in a pageant. The main girl wins but lets her sister have the win and her grandmother says she needs to learn how to win.
As adults the main girl is in love with this guy but he gets with her sister. This sister runs away before the wedding, so he marries the main girl instead. Her sister comes back threatening suicide if she doesn't get the guy. Some singing in movie; her sister had run away to be a model or actress.

Your question is slightly confusing, Please let me know if I'd interpreted correctly. They are twins? If not, please differentiate them by using the terms, younger and older. One of the sisters loved a guy but he chose the other? Who runs away before wedding, the one in the relationship? And the guy married the other one (the lady who he's not been in relationship with)?

@Sarah It seems you have two different user accounts. In order to better be able to use the site to its fullest, including being able to comment on and edit your posts, as well as accept potentially correct answers, you might want to register one of your accounts and merge it with the other one by following the procedure described here.

Sounds like you're looking for Aaina from 1993.

Roma (Amrita Singh) and Reema Mathur (Juhi Chawla) are the daughters of Mr. Mathur (Saeed Jaffery), a wealthy businessman. Roma, the older one, has always been spoiled, gets everything she desires, and is very competitive. Reema is quite reserved and usually lets her sister take the spotlight. [...] The only similarity is that the sisters fall in love with the same man, Ravi Saxena (Jackie Shroff).
Always the center of attention, Roma catches his eye first. Reema is heartbroken but puts on a brave face. Ravi and Roma decide to get married. Unfortunately, Roma is ambitious to be a star in a film and gets an offer on the day of her wedding. She accepts and abandons Ravi minutes before their wedding. Ravi is furious and, in turn, marries Reema to save the honor of her family.

Roma then returns and attempts suicide in order to get Ravi back. Here's the trailer:




Matches the description exactly, I'm sure OP is looking for this one.
